# Choosing 6 points in $\mathbb{P^2}$ leaves 4 independent cubics vanishing at these points

Tags: matrices, algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Basically title: Suppose we choose 6 points in $\mathbb{P^2}$ in sufficiently random position (no 3 of them on the same line). The dimension of the space of homogeneous cubics in the plane is 10, so there will be 4 independent cubic vanishing at the 6 points, but how do we show this? I recall seeing a matrix proof by constructing the matrix of coefficients and wanting it to have full rank, but I do not remember the details of the proof, can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean, the outline you mention is exactly the answer to this. The condition of "evaluates to $0$ at point $p$" is a linear condition on the coefficients, and so vanishing on 6 points enforces 6 linear conditions. With a sufficiently general position they're independent. Are you looking for a verification that no 3 collinear is a sufficient general position condition, or something else?

Comment: @KReiser no as you said I understand the general outline of the proof, but atm I'm a bit stuck about constructing the matrix and working with its rank, so I was thinking maybe if I saw it written one time I would remember it fully